# How to decode json loop data using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I am working in package tracking API and it return data in json

I am using javascript to output the data

The first three outputs are perfect, but the issue is "current_status" and "statuses" has indented/nested data, how to output them?

```js
const data = {
  "packet_id": "0024-00003711",
  "consignee_name": "Nasir maqbool",
  "destination": "Lahore",
  "current_status": {
    "status": "Assigned to Courier",
    "datetime": "2020-12-27T17:55:05.414Z",
    "comment": null
  },
  "statuses": [{
    "status": "Pickup request sent",
    "datetime": "2020-12-27T09:55:41.295Z",
    "comment": null
  }, {
    "status": "Booked",
    "datetime": "2020-12-26T10:13:15.333Z",
    "comment": null
  }]
}

let html = "";

html += '<div><strong>Packet Id:</strong> ' + data.packet_id + '</div>';
html += '<div><strong>Consignee Name:</strong> ' + data.consignee_name + '</div>';
html += '<div><strong>Destination:</strong> ' + data.destination + '</div>';
html += '<div><strong>Current Status:</strong>???</div>';
html += '<div><strong>Status:</strong> ???</div>';
$("#response").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: `currentstatus` is not a single value.`currentstatus` has object in its value

Comment: For the current_status
Just like this:
```html += '<div><strong>Current Status:</strong>+data.current_status.status+ </div>';```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]. Since the ajax works, no need to post that part at all

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need loop over `arrays` and you have to decide what you need out of `objects`!!

for the arrays check this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map

```js
const data = { "packet_id": "0024-00003711", "consignee_name": "Nasir maqbool", "destination": "Lahore", "current_status": { "status": "Assigned to Courier", "datetime": "2020-12-27T17:55:05.414Z", "comment": null }, "statuses": [{ "status": "Pickup request sent", "datetime": "2020-12-27T09:55:41.295Z", "comment": null }, { "status": "Booked", "datetime": "2020-12-26T10:13:15.333Z", "comment": null }] };


const curStatus = Object.entries(data.current_status)
  .map(entr => `<li>${entr[0]}:${entr[1]}</li>`) // map the entries 
  .join("") // join
  
const statuses = data.statuses
  .map(ent => Object.entries(ent) // map each status
    .map(entr => `<li>${entr[0]}:${entr[1]}</li>`) // map the entries in the statuses
      .join("") // join
  ).join("</ul><hr><ul>") // join with a separator
  
const html = `<div><strong>Packet Id:</strong>${data.packet_id}</div>
<div><strong>Consignee Name:</strong>${data.consignee_name}</div>
<div><strong>Destination:</strong>${data.destination}</div>
<div><strong>Current Status:</strong><ul>${curStatus}</ul></div>
<div><strong>Previous statuses:</strong><ul>${statuses}</ul></div>`
$("#response").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response"></div>
```